# How to decode \u{61}lert to alert with Perl

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, xss

To prevent XSS I am using white list to block selected strings.
My Perl script blocks 'alert' but I found that it doesn't blocks '\U{61}lert'.
I wish to decode all strings before validating them so I tried MANY ways to convert '\U{61}lert' to 'alert' but couldn't find a way to do that with Perl (I am able to convert other formats, like \U62lert but not with parenthesis).

What is this format that using parenthesis?
Is there an easy and safe way to do that? (e.g. with the module 'Encode').

I don't want to deal with other XSS validation methods at the moment as they requires deep changes/tests while I need to have prompt solution (at least for now).

Thanks in advance!
Mike

Comment: Can you show your Perl script so we have an idea on how you have things set up?

Answer (score 3):

Backslashes and curly braces need to be backslashed. Use `/e` to interpret the replacement as code:

```
echo '\u{61}lert' | perl -pe 's/\\u\{([0-9]+)\}/chr hex $1/ge'
alert
```

Comment: Thanks. I meant to some global solution that will also block other similar encodings (i.e. \u0061).

Comment: Do you also want to cover `&#x61;`? What else?

Comment: Any variation of encoding I will be able to take the string that the user put in the URL and convert it (to utf8) to match if it's invalid strings.
I am familiar with regex but it seems that there are many variations of encodings that regex can miss.

Comment: There's no way how to catch "any variation of encoding". You need to know which ones you want to catch.